# Perl adding Lines into a Multi-Dimensional Hash

Tags: perl, hashmap

Hello I want to split a Line and add the Values in to a multi dimensional Hash. This is how the Lines look like:

```
__DATA__
49839382;Test1;bgsae;npvxs
49839384;Test2;bgsae;npvxs
49839387;Test3;bgsae;npvxs
```

So what I am doing now is:

```
my %prefix = map { chomp; split ';' } <DATA>;
```

But now I can only access Test1 with:

```
print $prefix{"49839382"}
```

But how can I also add the bgsae to the Hash so I can access is with

```
$prefix{"49839382"}{"Test1"}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What structure are you trying to build?

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %prefix = map { chomp (my @fields = split /;/); $fields[0] => { @fields[1 .. $#fields] }  } <DATA>;
print Dumper \%prefix;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '49839384' => {
                          'Test2' => 'bgsae',
                          'npvxs' => undef
                        },
          '49839382' => {
                          'Test1' => 'bgsae',
                          'npvxs' => undef
                        },
          '49839387' => {
                          'npvxs' => undef,
                          'Test3' => 'bgsae'
                        }
        };
```

Or do you need a deeper hash?

```
my %prefix;
for (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $ref = \%prefix;
    for (split /;/) {
        warn "[$_]";
        $ref->{$_} = {};
        $ref = $ref->{$_};
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '49839384' => {
                      'Test2' => {
                                   'bgsae' => {
                                                'npvxs' => {}
                                              }
                                 }
                    },
      '49839382' => {
                      'Test1' => {
                                   'bgsae' => {
                                                'npvxs' => {}
                                              }
                                 }
                    },
      '49839387' => {
                      'Test3' => {
                                   'bgsae' => {
                                                'npvxs' => {}
                                              }
                                 }
                    }
    };
```

Comment: @slayedbylucifer: There's no `map` in the second example :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you need the data for, but at a guess you want something more like this.

It builds a hash of arrays, using the first field as the key for the data, and the remaining three in an array for the value. So you can access the test number as `$data{'49839382'}[0]` etc.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = map {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /;/;
  shift @fields => \@fields;
} <DATA>;

use Data::Dumper;
print Data::Dumper->Dump([\%data], ['*data']);

__DATA__
49839382;Test1;bgsae;npvxs
49839384;Test2;bgsae;npvxs
49839387;Test3;bgsae;npvxs
```

**output**

```
%data = (
      '49839384' => [
                      'Test2',
                      'bgsae',
                      'npvxs'
                    ],
      '49839382' => [
                      'Test1',
                      'bgsae',
                      'npvxs'
                    ],
      '49839387' => [
                      'Test3',
                      'bgsae',
                      'npvxs'
                    ]
    );
```